# Is it good way to unit test this method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I need to test this method using Junit/Mockito.
Actually, I couldn't write properly test with Mockito, so I've used my own input instead of mocking scanner. I don't know if I made it right. (anybody knows how to make it with mockito?)

Here is my method that I want to test:

```
public RentingACar rentACar(Scanner input) {
    RentingACar rentingACar = new RentingACar();

    System.out.print("Brand: ");
    rentingACar.setBrand(input.next());
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    rentingACar.setName(input.next());
    System.out.print("Surname: ");
    rentingACar.setSurname(input.next());
    System.out.print("Rent Date: ");
    rentingACar.setRentDate(input.next());
    System.out.print("Client number: ");
    rentingACar.setClientNumber(input.nextInt());

    return rentingACar;
}
```

Here is my test:

```
@Test
void rentACar() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Mazda\nPeter\nParker\n20.02\n1234");
    ClientDataGetter clientDataGetter = new ClientDataGetter();

    RentingACar rentingACar = clientDataGetter.rentACar(scanner);

    assertNotNull(rentingACar);

    assertEquals("Mazda", rentingACar.getBrand());
    assertEquals("Peter", rentingACar.getName());
    assertEquals("Parker", rentingACar.getSurname());
    assertEquals("20.02", rentingACar.getRentDate());
    assertEquals(1234, rentingACar.getClientNumber());
}
```

Does it make any sense?

Comment: This is simply my **opinion** (hint, hint - this is likely an off-topic question for that reason), but I don't see anything wrong with what you have there.

Comment: Might be a fit for [codereview.se]. I'm not active there, so I can't judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to use Mockito when you don't need it, hell, you have more problems to write it using Mockito than without it? Mockito is the completely last resort option (for example mocking a database or external service), and even then it's questionable if you should use it or not (instead of just writing your own `FakeDatabase` or `FakeExternalService`). Definitely not needed here, how would a mocked `Scanner` even help?

I'd say your way is fine, even though the code you are testing leaves a lot to be desired. Since this question is about testing I'm not gonna talk about the code itself.

You tested only so called happy-path, that means the case where output is perfect and everything works correctly.

What you also need to do is to test the edge cases (when the input is at maximum/minimum, like L.MIN_VALUE/0/Long.MAX_VALUE in numbers, 0 length in Strings etc.), for example with empty/one letter names, client number starting with 0.

And after all you need to test if the input is simply bad: no `\n` signs, no date where the date should be etc., lot of possibilities here. You are probably gonna see that your code is not enough and you will have to change it (add some validation of input perhaps). This is why it's good to start with tests (test-driven development), you can see before writing the code that you are gonna have to do that validation and you will be prepared for that. This is the simple case, but it's not always so easy to add important functionality to already existing code, and it can even be risky if that code is already used by someone. I've seen a lot of situations when someone needs to do a modification like that, but it's simply not possible without a huge refactoring, so this is what they do (please, never do it):

```java
if(mySpecialCase) {
  // all the logic
} else {
  // all the logic, almost identical to the logic above
}
```

Edit: Replying to your comment - `Why is it bad practice to make if conditions?`

I'm not just talking about the `if` conditions here. I'm talking about the potential code duplication in both `if` branches, they will most likely have very similar code. Imagine you have another change to make, you have to add another `if` to both of the branches, it becomes a mess.

`If` conditions should also not be overused, especially if it comes down to a lot of different branches. It's hard to debug, test, and see what's going on just by looking at the code. It's really important that someone (or you) knows what the code does just by looking at it and analyzing it. Solving this is usually not easy and involves using some [design patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns), like [decorator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator), sometimes even a simple [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) can help a lot.

Comment: Actually, it's my first bigger project and my first tests. If I understood well, I should start from the beggining about some other conditions like you said: if user input bad rent or client number start with 0. If I don't write `\n` test will fail, because of bad input. So I can't test it, because my code is not prepare well, but for this moment Im not gonna repair it. I tried to focus on improving my coding skills. :)

Comment: Why is it bad practice to make if conditions?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would write the test using Mockito.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class ClientDataGetterTest {

    ClientDataGetter clientDataGetter = new ClientDataGetter();

    @Test
    public void testRentACar() {
       // define input data (test Scanner object)
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Mazda\nPeter\nParker\n20.02\n1234");

        // call you method
        RentingACar rentACar = spy(new RentingACar());
        clientDataGetter.rentACar(rentACar, scanner);

        // Verify that the methods were called with exact parameter values and exactly one time each
        verify(rentACar, times(1)).setBrand("Mazda");
        verify(rentACar, times(1)).setName("Peter");
        verify(rentACar, times(1)).setSurname("Parker");
        verify(rentACar, times(1)).setRentDate("20.02");
        verify(rentACar, times(1)).setClientNumber(1234);

        // Old code
/*
        //check the results
        assertEquals("Mazda", rentingACar.getBrand());
        assertEquals("Peter", rentingACar.getName());
        assertEquals("Parker", rentingACar.getSurname());
        assertEquals("20.02", rentingACar.getRentDate());
        assertEquals(1234, rentingACar.getClientNumber());
*/
    }
```

Mockito is making sure that your setters are called.

Personally I think if your RentingACar looks like a simple POJO, so there is no need to mock it like I did, your way is fine.

#### Potential change that does not work.

You could use Mockito for Scanner by defining it like this: // define mock for the scanner

```
Scanner scanner = mock(Scanner.class);
when(scanner.next()).thenReturn("Mazda","Peter","Parker","20.02","1234");
```

but mockito cannot mock final classes. Standard java.util.Scanner is final class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Igor! I will leave test like I made it.